# Is it possible to redefine destructor?

Tags: c++

I've encountered a problem with "redefineing" destructor. The thing is I have been given a definition of struct that i cannot modify. It is a "leaf" of a tree. Goal is to free only a part of the tree while returning a pointer to the remaining subtree. My idea is to use reference counting. 
This is the given code:

```
struct TLeaf {
   TLeaf* m_L;
   TLeaf* m_R;
   ~TLeaf(void) {
     delete m_L;
     delete m_R;
   }
}
```

Is there at least way to avoid calling this destructor? Actually any idea is acceptable. :D

Thank you very much good people of Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Are you saying you cannot change this code? And you need to define new behavior in a subclass?

Comment: override delete operator (don't do this)

Comment: If it's an __leaf__, shouldn't it be the last node in a tree? If so - it shouldn't have subtrees.

Comment: you shouldn't be deleting things in a destructor that weren't allocated in a constructor.

Comment: @RedAlert I agree, but note he said he can't change this code.

Comment: Technically it is not a classic tree. One node can be pointed at by many nodes. It implements CYK algorithm generating a parsing tree. It might be a bad idea and i should probably choose a different approach.

Comment: If you are deleting in your destructor, and do not have a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, you are going to have some issues ...

Answer (score 4):

You could `nullptr` out the values before you delete the node. `delete ptr` where `ptr` is `nullptr` is safe and does nothing

```
TLeaf* ltmp = node->m_L;
TLeaf* rtmp = node->m_R;

node->m_L = nullptr;
node->m_R = nullptr;

delete node;

// now use ltmp and rtmp as you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify the TLeaf, what you can do is to modify the user code.

0) If you are using heap allocation, try `operator delete(p)` instead of `delete p`.

1) If you are using stack allocation, avoid directly using the type `TLeaf`:

```
char leaf[sizeof(TLeaf)];
new (leaf) TLeaf(...); // placement new
```