# Is it possible NOT to call parent destructor?

Tags: c++

I've been given a struct that I cannot modify. Is it possible to provide my destructor and use it instead of the given one? Or maybe define my struct and then typecast it when needed? Inheritance is also an option, but didn't manage to skip call of parent destructor.

```
//Given struct
struct TA {
  ~TA() {
    delete m_L;
    delete m_R;
  }
  TA* m_L;
  TA* m_R;
};

//What i need
struct TB {
  ~TB() {
    if (m_L) m_L->destroy();
    if (m_R) m_R->destroy();
  }
  void destroy() {
    if (!--nRefernece) delete this;
  }
  int nRefernece;
  TB* m_L;
  TB* m_R;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you need `std::shared_ptr` (`boost::shared_ptr`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to redefine destructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392561/is-it-possible-to-redefine-destructor)

Comment: @Greg yes, `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter sound like the most promising solution

Comment: OK, sounds good to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dirty hack, but it is effective in your situation:
You can simply do the calls to `destroy()` in the destructor of a derived class, *and set the variables `m_L` and `m_R` to zero* before returning from your destructor. `delete` is defined to do nothing if passed a null pointer, so, you have effectively deactivated the code within the base class destructor.

```
struct TB : TA {
  ~TB() {
    if (m_L) ((TB*)m_L)->destroy();
    if (m_R) ((TB*)m_R)->destroy();
    m_L = m_R = 0;
  }
  void destroy() {
    if (!--nReference) delete this;
  }
  int nReference;
};
```

Comment: So this might be motivated by reference counting? In the bigger picture it would be nice to get motivation of this. Variable name change to nReference would give better indication.

Comment: @user2672165 `nRefernece` was copy paste from the question. I'll fix it. Apart from that, my answer is really nothing more than a dirty hack for the specific problem of the OP. I would not recommend to write such destructors, unless you are forced to.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. :) Although it is a dirty little trick, it works like a charm in this exact case.

Answer (score 5):

No. If you don't want a parent destructor to be called, don't use inheritance.

Comment: +1 Inheritance is not the only tool we have, use it properly. OTOH I think you should extend the answer providing a more in depth reason, and an alternative solution.

Comment: @Manu343726: I wasn't quite sure what problem the author really wanted to solve, but the technical question itself was quite clear and could only be answered with a clear "no", IMO.

Comment: Also one may add the consequenses of destructor in base class not being virtual.